# Anyone here old enough to remember ActionScript 2.0 - colour overlay question

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I am working on a new HUD widget mod for Skyrim, which unfortunately still uses AS 2.0 (ikr...).  One key feature of the widget is a real-time editor mode which allows users to reposition/scale/rotate/etc each element of the widget.  As the user cycles through the elements I am currently using the setRGB method to apply a highlight colour to the selected element (or group of elements).  The problem with this is that setRGB is destructive, so when applied to the icons there is no way of getting them back to their original state.  This wouldn't be an issue if the icons were plain white in the first place as I could simply use setRGB to set them back to white.  However several of the icons are more than a single colour and I haven't been able to find a way to refresh them to remove the highlight colour.

I wanted to use GlowFilter to apply the highlight as an outer glow rather than an overlay, but for whatever reason GlowFilter never seems to show up in game.

I have also thought about using duplicateMovieClip to create a copy of the selected element on top of itself and apply the setRGB to that, then removeMovieClip when the element is cycled, but in AS2 this is a very longwinded process!  It is also complicated further by the fact that several of the movieclips contain timelines so I'd have to get the current frame on the original and set it on the duplicate, and others are instances of other classes which need initialised before they show correctly.

If anyone has any suggestions as to how best I could achieve a removable, non-destructive colour overlay or outer glow I would be delighted to hear from you.

UPDATE: Further experimentation and I can actually confirm that the filters do work, however I can only apply then to my TextField elements.  I can't for the life of me get them to apply to my movieclips, all of which contain nested clips (some if which also contain nested clips and so on).  I've tried using loop..if to iterate through the nested clips and apply the filters to each instance but no joy.  So why is it that setRGB works on the ultimate parent clip, but using the movieclip filters property doesn't?  I thought I might have to use cacheToBitmap but the reference manual tells me that's done automatically when you apply the filter.

Comment: Try **ColorMatrixFilter** page 423/424 here: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/flash/ActionScript2Reference.pdf If that doesn't work, uhm... You can **createEmptyMovieClip()**, draw a square of needed color, put it under the original icon then set original icon as a **MovieClip.setMask(...)** of that colored square. The **cacheAsBitmap = true**, applied to both, ensures the alpha-channel of the mask is taken into account. Forgive me if none of that actually works, it's been 10 years, my memories are a bit fuzzy.

Comment: I've updated the op confirming that the filters do work, however I can only apply then to my TextField elements. I can't get them to apply to movieclips, all of which contain nested clips (some if which also contain nested clips). I've tried using loop..if to iterate through the nested clips and apply the filters to each instance but no joy. So why is it that setRGB works on the ultimate parent clip, but using the movieclip filters property doesn't? I thought I might have to use cacheToBitmap but the reference manual tells me that's done automatically when you apply the filter.

Comment: The point is, these are totally different cases. The mask variant doesn't suppose setting any filters, that's why you will need to set **cacheAsBitmap** explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't frame my last question very well.  I was wondering why using var myColor:Color = new Color(my_mc);
myColor.setRGB(highlightColor);     works when my_mc is the ultimate parent clip, yet applying the filters to the same clip (which automatically sets cacheAsBitmap to true) doesn't work, regardless of which filter I try (GlowFilter, DropShadowFilter, ColorMatrixFilter).

Comment: I took some reading of that manual I posted earlier. It says that **Color** class is deprecated since Flash Player 8 while filters only available since Flash Player 8. That kinda questions what kind of Flash Player build is used there and what it's capabilities are.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I have GlowFilter and DropShadowFilter working perfectly well for the TextField elements, just nothing I try gets them to apply to the movieclips containing graphical elements. Today I went through the entire fla and converted every Graphic and Shape to movieclip because I read filters can only be applied to movieclip, button or TextField elements but still no different. I also tried setting cacheAsBitmap to true on the clips before I applied the filters just in case but again no change.  I'm sure I must be missing something obvious here.